# linked list deleting nodes based on given string data type

Tags: c++

guys can help me with my definition?

based on deleting linked list node on nth position that i saw on youtube, instead of using int data type, i tried using string type, the code works, but instead of deleting the specific node, it deletes the node AFTER the specific node

```
 void deletePower(string kat) 
 {
     struct  CValue* temp1 = head;
     struct  Lnama* temp2 = newHead;
     if (temp2->kat == kat) 
     {
         head = temp1->next;
         newHead = temp2->after;
         delete temp1;
         delete temp2;
         return;
     }

     while(temp2->kat != kat)
     {
         temp1 = temp1->next;
         temp2 = temp2 ->after;
     }

     struct   CValue* temp3 = temp1->next;
     struct  Lnama* temp4 = temp2->after;
     temp2->after = temp4->after;
     temp1->next = temp3->next;
     delete temp3;
     delete temp4;
}
```

In my main function:

```
int main()
{
    string first;
    head = NULL;
    newHead = NULL;
    insertMYR(5,1);
    insertMYR(10,2);
    insertMYR(56,3);
    insertMYR(56,4);
    insertLIST("USD",1);
    insertLIST("POUND",2);
    insertLIST("YEN",3);
    insertLIST("RUPIAH",4);
    display();

    cin>>first;
    deletePower(first);

    display();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

when i delete pound, it will delete yen instead, if i delete rupiah, well after rupiah is null, so yeah...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
while(temp2->kat != kat)
{
    temp1 = temp1->next;
    temp2 = temp2 ->after;
}
```

The loop exits when `temp2->kat == kat` which means that `temp1` and `temp2` point to the nodes you want to delete when the loop is done. You then proceed to delete `temp3` and `temp4` which are the nodes after that.

Change the condition to `while(temp2->after->kat != kat)` and you should be deleting the proper node.

Comment: So that means i need to exit the loop before temp2 points to node that i want to delete?

Comment: yes, because you need to point the node before the node you delete to the node after the one you delete (which is what the rest of your code is doing).

Comment: No worries, please accept the answer if you feel like it adequately answered your problem!